# Skobbler SDK for Android 2.1.0: Crash with getScreenshot method

Tags: android, sdk, skmaps

I use SKMapSurfaceView.getScreenshot() for take screenshot with rendered map and get crash for 4.4.2 device with full hd screen:

Android: 4.4.2
Manufacturer: samsung
Model: SM-G900H

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:997)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1021)
    at com.skobbler.ngx.map.MapRenderer.a(SourceFile:1134)
    at com.skobbler.ngx.map.MapRenderer.onDrawFrame(SourceFile:391)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1532)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1249)
```

Comment: how is this connected to skmaps? Under which circumstances are you experiencing this crash?

Comment: This connected to skmaps because I use this [method](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.1.0/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKMapSurfaceView.html#getScreenshot()) to get screenshot with map

Comment: @Ando I use code from documentation to take screenshot

`mapView.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mapView.requestScreenshot();
    synchronized (mapView) {
        mapView.requestRender();
        try {
             mapView.wait();
             mapBitmap = mapView.getScreenshot();
         } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return null;
         }
     }`

Comment: ok - understood - let us look into it then

Comment: @Ando Do you have any updates?

Comment: We tried this scenario with 2.2 with the code running on an AsyncTask when a certain button is pressed and it worked on a number of devices without issues - can you retest with the 2.2 version of the SDK?

Comment: If you try running the screenshot related code from a different thread (other than the UI thread), does the crash still occur in this case?